# Printing HTML pages differes from browser to browser

Tags: html

I am trying to take printout an HTML (has 1 page)
Firefox 3.1 is taking 2 pages
and Firefox 3.5 is taking 1 page.
Donno what IE does.
Is there any way to globalize the printing thing (thru css or any method) so that it will print exact page that it shows.

Comment: Did you know that Firefox 3.5 is actually the same version as Firefox 3.1?

Comment: Any idea why the both prints differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to specify a unique style sheet for printing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

vs.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" media="screen" />
```

Then in your print css use a standard font, basic colors and hide any adds, etc.

```
/* basic white on bl;ack 12pt font */
body {
  font-family : "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size : 12pt;
  color : #000000;
  background : #ffffff;
}
/* Underline Links */
a {
  text-decoration : underline;
  color : #0000ff;
}
/* hide web-only content */
#navDiv, #adDiv, #etc {
  display : none;
}
```

Comment: It might be wise to reset add some reset rules which will reset everything (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) before you start to add any formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use CSS. Not always an easy task though. You could start [here](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=PrintStylesheets).

Answer (score 0):

If you want precise printing, I'd suggest you output PDFs instead. As for html, you want to use a separate css file for printing, but still, just have to test each individual browser you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is the `print` media type and its `page` property, but that has extremely poor support in all major browsers. I think you'll be stuck with inconsistent print rendering for some time. You could read ALA's [Going to Print](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) for tips, though.